# Undefined symbols for x86_64 architecture on mac

Tags: macos, fortran, x86-64, fftw

I am trying to compile a code that uses the FFTW libraries. I have installed these and have checked using lipo that they are installed for x86_64 architecture. However when I try to compile I get the following error

```
mpif90 -r8 -O3 -assume byterecl -u -I/usr/local/mpich2/include -I/usr/local/fftw_215_mpich2/include -L/usr/local/fftw_215_mpich2/lib -I./OBJ/ ./SRC/tt_main.f90  ./OBJ/xx_exter.o ./OBJ/tt_fft.o ./OBJ/tt_force.o ./OBJ/tt_init.o ./OBJ/tt_io.o ./OBJ/tt_les.o  ./OBJ/tt_update.o ./OBJ/tt_stat.o ./OBJ/tt_mod.o ./OBJ/xx_mod.o  -o turbo  -ldfftw -ldrfftw -ldfftw_mpi -ldrfftw_mpi -lm
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_rfftwnd_f77_mpi_", referenced from:
      _fft3ds_ in tt_fft.o
      _ifft3ds_ in tt_fft.o
  "_rfftwnd_f77_mpi_create_plan_", referenced from:
      _init_fft3d_ in tt_fft.o
  "_rfftwnd_f77_mpi_local_sizes_", referenced from:
      _init_fft3d_ in tt_fft.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
make[1]: *** [turb] Error 1
make: *** [turbo] Error 2
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Should add that this is a code which was written by somebody else and has been used multiple times by other people. As such the error should be in my linking or my installation of the libraries and not in the code itself.

Comment: Don't know, if this helps, but there is a space too much between `-` and `I/usr/local/fftw_215_mpich2/include`.

Comment: That space doesn't seem to be there in my terminal, must have popped up when I copied it across. Thanks though!